# WordPress formatting issues with front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Following this tutorial: 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial

The tutorial instructs me to create an index.php with the contents:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- loop-->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This creates a template with my header on top and footer at the bottom. Then, the tutorial instructs me to create a front-page.php with the contents:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, the same thing as index.php minus a few lines of code, most importantly the `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` commands. The problem is that, when I create this page, my front page no longer has either its header or its footer, or the formatting that lives within the header and footer.

Yet, on the tutorial, the header, footer, and formatting still apply on the front page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the tutorial guy forgot this lines. Just keep `get_header();` and `get_footer();` in your `front-page.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong. The developer probably forgot to mention adding it, that's all.

When you use `front-page.php`, WordPress doesn't use `index.php` when rendering the front page and there is no way to include the header and the footer unless you add `get_header()` and `get_footer()` to `front-page.php`.

Add the header and the footer and you should see your front page as the screenshot in the tutorial, and notify the developer to fix this in his tutorial

Comment: Thank you Ahmed! Was weirded out because the guy who wrote the tutorial explicitly mentioned removing the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` commands for front-page.php

Comment: I can't find the section that states removing the header and footer. I only found `remove the get_title()`. He just forgot to add it to the code

Comment: You're right. It says only to remove the `get_title()`--I guess it's the part where it says "and your code should look like this"--while excluding two important tags.

Answer (score 0):

hi Matt create a page home  template and call header and footer in it then  you an call posts its worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom header and footer as well.

Create your custom header like "header-custom.php"

to include this header you need `<?php get_header('custom'); ?>` after - is the name of your custom header, when you call the header you need to insert name inside the function like i did above.

for footer also same login & sider bar also same logic.

footer-custom.php, sidebar-custom.php

```
<?php
get_footer('custom');
?>

<?php 
get_sidebar('custom');
?>
```

Thanks.